# Mathjax MathJax_MSIE_Frame issue on IE 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, mathjax

I am using Mathjax in my project. For IE 10, the `MathJax_MSIE_Frame` div is generated.

I want to change the default style of this div. So I have added the style in Mathjax initialize

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
     styles: {
         '#MathJax_MSIE_Frame': {
           'position': 'static',
           'height': '0',
           'overflow': 'hidden',
           'visibility': 'hidden',
           'display': 'none'
         }
     },
     showMathMenu: false,
 }
```

It works fine and the css is applied when the page is loading at first time.

The problem is when I refresh the same page again, this css is not getting applied for the MathJax_MSIE_Frame div.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `MathJax.Hub.Config` call is in a `<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">...</script>` block that appears *before* the `<script>` that loads `MathJax.js` itself.  If it is after, then it may not be visible to MathJax when MathJax does its configuration, and so won't be processed.  The timing for initial page loads and page refreshes are not the same, and so if you are getting different behavior in those two cases, this is often the problem.  You didn't show how your `MathJax.Hub.Config` call is placed in your page, but I suspect it is after loading MathJax, which is the problem.